# R Mongolite package: aggregrate, unwind, project

Tags: r, mongodb

My MongoDB has a collection with documents, and some of the documents have elements. To get a data frame in R, one needs to unwind the elements of the document "data". The statement (see below) within the aggregate () was written in Robomongo and works well.

```
con <- mongo(collection = "A",db = "B", url = "mongodb://abc")
h <- con$aggregate('[{"$match" : {}},
                     {"$project": {
                       "_data":1
                     }
                     },
                     {"$unwind": "$_data"},
                     {"$project": {
                     "Field1": "$_data.Field1",
                     "Field2": "$_data.Field2",
                     "Field3": "$_data.Field3",
                     "Field4": "$_data.Field4",
                     "Field5": "$_data.Field5",
                     "Field6": "$_data.Field6"
                     }
                     },
                     ]')
```

Alas, wenn running it from R using the Mongolit package I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: [{"$match" : {
                    _id:1
                    _data: 1}},

                {"$project": {
                  "_data":1
                }
                },
```

Please, can anyone adapt my statement to proper R mongolite-mongodb syntax?
Thanks a million!

Comment: What is the point of your empty $match query?

Comment: Try this first: aggregate('[{"$unwind":"$_data"}]')

Comment: remove the last comma.